# Fastest way to draw small particles in opengl?

Tags: opengl, graphics, software-engineering

Quick question : Which is the fastest method to render a large array of 4x4/8x8 particles in opengl ? Currently i spend 2triangles for each one but i think that its slow so i would really like to know if im doing it right.....

Comment: Just a reminder that since this is a performance question, you should *measure* the performance on your target platform, (a) to be sure it's really expensive enough to be worth worrying about and (b) to test the speedup of any proposed solutions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can draw points with OpenGL.

You want to call **glDrawArrays()** or **glDrawElements()** with **GL_POINTS** (instead of GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP or whatever you are using.)

This will draw points to the screen based on the current point size, which you can set via [glPointSize()](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glPointSize.xml). You can also alias these points, but in my experience not all drivers / hardware supports aliased points.

<strike>You can't texture these points; they are just a single color.</strike>

Comment: Thanks for the hint.Do you happen to know if i could do the GL_POINT Method with shaders so that i can map a texture to them aswell ?

Comment: You can use with shaders, but there is only one vertex for a point (at the center), so you may have a hard time coming up with tex coords. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5839095/sample-texture-in-gl-points-shaders looks like it talks a bit about this...

Comment: You can set a point sprite with GL_POINTS as well.

Comment: @user1010005 To texture map with GL_POINTS you could look into GL_POINT_SPRITE_ARB.  Also, I'm pretty sure that the points always end up occupying the same number of pixels on the screen, no matter how close or far you are from them.

Comment: @ktodisco, you can pass in the point size as an attribute. i achieved a decent star effect by doing this. to change the size in the vert shader, you assign the variable **gl_PointSize**

Comment: I'll accept the answer since the vertex buffering is one step closer to what im after.

Answer (score 3):

In core OpenGL 3.2 and above, [geometry shaders](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Geometry_Shader) are available for use.  To give a brief overview, you would only tell OpenGL to draw the points that represent the positions of your particles, and these points would pass through the vertex shader normally, but then when they get to the geometry shader, it constructs the rectangle (out of two tris) by emitting vertices to the next stage of the pipeline.  Along with the vertices you can programmatically generate normals and texture coordinates.

Since this is all done in hardware, I'm pretty sure it's the fastest way right now to render point-sprite particles.

Comment: This is probably a better solution than GL_POINTS, but it won't work for older OpenGL implementations (and OpenGL ES).

Comment: Sounds great but i plan to port my game to android platform :(

Comment: @user1010005 Just a tip, you should mention that when you ask the question, so we know what constraints to work with :)

Comment: I'm a beginner with opengl sorry D:

Comment: i would **LOVE** to see the geometry shader made available in OpenGL ES. )=

Comment: I would share it if i was good with shaders (: